# How usinghow can I access a session from twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I access `{{ app.session.get('user') }}`

[image]

I don't understand much about controllers I only have this is the one I use to control that template

```
//accedemos a las dependencias de Twig
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

//accedemos a la clase LoginModel para realizar operaciones a la base de datos
require_once './model/LoginModel.php';
require_once './core/ControladorBase.php';

class LoginController
{
    private $loader;
    private $twig;
    private $controladorBase;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->controladorBase = new ControladorBase();

        $this->loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('./view');
        $this->twig = new \Twig\Environment($this->loader);
    }
    
    /**
     * Muestra la página principal y el listado de empleados dados de alta
     * @throws \Twig\Error\LoaderError
     * @throws \Twig\Error\RuntimeError
     * @throws \Twig\Error\SyntaxError
     */
    public function index(){
        $session = new Session();
        $session->set('user', 'juan' );
        echo $this->twig->render('/login/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a "new" session, whilst you have to modify the existing one that `Symfony` initialised

Comment: app.session is part of the Symfony framework.  As far as I can tell from the code you posted, you are not actually using the framework, just some components.  It's going to be up to you to add any additional session related functionality probably via a Twig extension.  Or just use the actual framework.